# Dumb question: Concern regarding using backend server's REST API in React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, rest

Like in order to connect(basically making request's) our React app to our backend server we have to use backend REST API, like logging in user, fetching data from the backend.

But wouldn't using REST API on the React components make API available to every user and any malicious mind could create chaos or make unnecessary requests to the server(like using Postman).

Is there any way to hide API keys, I've seen another answer to a similar question on 'How to hide API Keys' but there's not a clear answer, some saying to prepend API with REACT_APP_ in a dotenv file but some saying this is not safe, although I've tried prepending REACT_APP_ but still API is visible on the front end.

Is there a solution available to this problem?

Comment: That why you need authentication and throttling.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "throttling"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a REST API from your react app does not expose those endpoints to the public. By virtue of that REST API existing, those endpoints are already exposed to the public and anyone in the public can use them. It's the *servers* job to make sure those endpoints are locked down and secure (requires authentication, etc), not the clients.

Comment: Like authenticating client on each incoming request?

Comment: Correct. That's actually a big use for cookies - after the user logs in, the server gives the client a cookie that informs the server that they logged in successfully. (cookies can be spoofed, so often some cryptography is involved so that the server can trust the cooke). Then, the user can give that cookie with each request to authenticate themself with each request.